# What's the maximum inventory size?

Tags: the-secret-world

You can increase your inventory size 10 slots at a time for an expenditure of Pax Romana.

What is the maximum size your inventory can reach in this manner?  Do you ever have to do anything other than spend PAX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This thread](http://forums.thesecretworld.com/showthread.php?t=45817) indicates that the maximum personal inventory space is 200 slots, purchased using PAX at an incremental cost for each additional purchase.

It appears that your personal bank space can be increased by 200 slots as well.

Comment: And you can get another 100 slots for free by creating a Cabal (via the Cabal bank).

Comment: Oops, I forgot to accept this...

Answer (score 3):

The maximum inventory size is 200.

I checked experimentally by buying until actually hitting the limit. After that the "+" button only gives the message that the maximum size has been reached.

The alternative to the inventory is using (and upgrading) your bank account to "swap out" items you don't need during the game, but want to keep. Up to 200 items here as well.

The "create a cabal" trick to get additional slots in the cabal bank (as opposed to your own bank account) is available only for those who do not join a "real" cabal, and only as long as they do. Once you join a real cabal, you have to leave your "one-man-cabal" and forfeit those extra slots.

On a related note, the maximum Skill Points (SP) you can collect are 40 - after that, you get the message "You did not receive any skill points as you have reached the cap of 40.".

Answer (score 2):

The maximum inventory size in the beta was 200 purchasable with PAX and you can buy 10 extra inventory from a vendor but its pretty expensive to get max inventory slots.

Comment: This is confusing - so you're saying 210?  Does the vendor in question not take PAX?

Comment: which vendor sells more bag space?

Answer (score 2):

It's 250 now, but those last upgrades are very, very costly (almost 1m from 200-210)